# Find the degree of field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

To find the degree of then extenstion $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) \leq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{2}, \omega_p)$$ where $\omega_p=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{p}}$

we have to find the degree of $$Irr(\omega_p , \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}))$$
right?? But how could I do that??

Comment: Do you want to find $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\omega_p):\mathbb{Q}]$ or $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\omega_p):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})]$?

Comment: The second one...

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[p]{2}$ is of degree $p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\omega_p$ is of degree $p-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226427/the-degree-of-the-extension-fa-b-if-the-degrees-of-fa-and-fb-are-re)

Comment: But how can I show that $\omega_p$ is degree $p-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$??

Comment: $p$ is prime, isn't it? You can show $\omega_p$ satisfies $f(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+x+1$. Now it is enough to show that the polynomial is irreducible. It is also enough to show that the polynomial $f(x+1)=(x+1)^{p-1}+(x+1)^{p-2}+\cdots + (x+1)+1$ is irreducible. Can you expand it and apply [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here goes a full solution: To prove irreducibility we will use [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion) extensively.

I assumed $p$ is prime. First of all note that $\sqrt[p]{2}$ is root of $x^{p}-2$ which is clearly irreducible by the above criterion. Therefore $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=p$. 
Note that $\omega_p$ is satisfied by $f(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+x+1$. Observe that
$$f(x+1)=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} (x+1)^i=\frac{(x+1)^{p}-1}{x}=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i+1}x^{i}$$
Again the criterion, helps us to conclude $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p):\mathbb{Q}]=p-1$
Hence by using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226427/the-degree-of-the-extension-fa-b-if-the-degrees-of-fa-and-fb-are-re) result we have
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\omega_p):\mathbb{Q}]=p(p-1)$$
Hence
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\omega_p):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})]=\frac{[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\omega_p):\mathbb{Q}]}{[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]}=\frac{p(p-1)}{p}=p-1$$

Comment: I understand!! Thank you very much!!! :-)